# Writing to a PORT does not change its state

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, xc8

I have the following program - Using XC8 C Compiler on MPLAB and the microcontroller is PIC16F877.

```
int main()
{
  TRISB = 0x00;
  while(1)
  {
    PORTB = 0xFF;
    __delay_ms(1000);
    PORTB = 0x00;
    __delay_ms(1000); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I have LED connected to the output pins of PORTB. BUT there is no blinking.

However, when I do this on individual pins, it works perfectly: Eg:

```
RB0 = 1;
RB1 = 0;
RB2 = 1;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try writing 0x07 and 0x00 to PORTB instead of 0xFF.

Comment: Did you check visually or with an oscilloscope ? If something is wrong with the timing it might blink too fast.

Comment: Possibly over current?

Have you tried setting all your PORTB on with the individual flags? Ex. `RB0 = 1; RB1 = 1; RB2 = 1; ...`

Comment: try to disable the comparators to get sure they are really off. For me it solved a simular problem.